# Adding a Button to Activity Causes a Runtime Exception

Tags: android

I am creating a tab based application, and which is in the prototype stage.  I have created the necessary tabs that display basic content (as described in the Android docs).  Now I am trying to add a few buttons to one of the activities, however, instantiating a new Button creates a runtime exception:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    private Button menuBTN = new Button( this );


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView( this );
        textview.setText( "This is the main application entry, and home screen" );
        this.setContentView( textview );

        this.getMenuBTN().setText("Menu");


//        this.addContentView( this.getMenuBTN(), new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));
    }
```

If I do not create the button at all, the basic application starts normally.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Adding textview and button to the screen? If so, use a layout to accomodate both view. 
\nAnyway, Please don't put creating button on top before **onCreate()**. using **this** only comes after **onCreate()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the button's layout programatically, but I would recommend that you define it in XML and then point to it by:

```
menuBTN = (Button)findViewByID(R.id.your_menubutton_id_in_xml);
```

You would then need to setContentView() to the xml layout where the button is.

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_xml);
```

Comment: You're, but for now this is just a quick prototype to show the powers that be.

Comment: On that note, where could I find a good resource on separating the layout into separate xml files?

Answer (score 2):

This it the bad line:

```
private Button menuBTN = new Button( this );
```

You should do this instead:

```
private Button menuBTN;
```

then within create you can call:

```
menuBTN = new Button( this );
```

The activity isn't ready for use before onCreate is called so you shouldn't reference it before that point.